# Problems to run Stylus compiler

Tags: stylus

I install Stylus with: `npm install stylus -g`
without problem in: `...AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylus\node_modules`
but when you run the command : `Stylus estilo.styl` for compile the file i have to following  error: `'Stylus' is not recognized as an internal or external command.`

Comment: The error message you are receiving is a rather mundane error message.   It means "I can't find the executable you specified."

Answer (score 0):

Stylus is not in your path. Add the path to Stylus to PATH in your environment variables. If it's there already, you may need to start a new command window.

Comment: Why didn't the installer add it to the path?  Isn't that sort of standard procedure for compilers?

Comment: It's possible that it did, and the OP needs to restart his command window.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows System Settings(Properties), and Select Environment settings -> User Variable section and edit the path value

**C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm**

username will be the username for your account like: deepak
**C:\users\deepak\AppData\Roaming\npm**

[image: Demo Pic]